# C# fetch data using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to `C# Linq`. I am running a restful service and for that I need to implement a function, and after that using that function I want to call my `Webservice` and `WebClient` as well,
I want to use database **Student**, please tell me some suggestion, or the function code so that I may fetch data from SQL,

Either I have to add a `LinqtoSQl` file in my service project or I may achieve my Goal using Just a Function.
Please Help,
My Student table has following columns,

```
ID  
FirstName  
LastName  
Email  
DOB  
Religion  
Studentof  
ContactNumber  
Address  
AdmissionDate
```

for being Simple:
you may code for the following SQL Query,

> Select * from Student where FirstName="Myname";

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "linq/?id={id}")]
string linq(string id);    
public string linq(string id) 
{
    return "This function should return Linq to SQL Result" + id;
}
```

Comment: `var result = Student.Where(x=>x.FirstName=="Myname")`

Comment: Dear please answer throughly,

Comment: either i need to add just a function or LinqtoSql file as well,??
Please answer in Explaination...

Comment: Go through this article :--http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46422/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Adding-Updating-Deleting-Data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using(Var db = new DataContext())
{
    Var studentes = db.Students.Where(s => s.FirstName == "MyName").ToList();
}
```

> where **DataContext** is the context where you put the classes in.

Comment: Should I add Linq to Sql to my project, or by just adding this function can lead me to get rid of this problem

Answer (score -1):

On your solution explorer click right on your project name then add > New item.. In the window it opens select create a new LINQ to SQL CLASSES and give a name say DataContext and click ok.

Now you should open DataContext.dbml from solution explorer you just created.
Then you have to drag and drop the tables you want to use from your database and save changes.

From here you can follow Ali Baghdadi answer.

Or if you want to use a select statement to fetch data like:

```
DataContext DbGet = new DataContext();
var qGet = from q in DbGet.tblStudent where q.ID == this.txtID.Text select Name =      q.Name , LastName = q.lastname;
this.Datagridview.DataSource = qGet.ToList;
```

//also :

```
foreach (object l in qGet) {
this.txtName.Text = l.Name;
    this.txtLastName.text = l.LastName;

}
```

This how you fetch data using Linq to Sql

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Milot25 , You understtod my problem well,